# ModX getResources template not receiving TVs

Tags: templates, modx, modx-revolution, television, getresource

I have the following getResources line:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`5` &tpl=`projlink` ]]
```

Then in the chunk I am using as a template (projlink) I have:

```
<div class="projname">[[+pagetitle]]</div>
<div class="projinfo">[[+tv.projinfo]]</div>
```

Now the pagetitle displays fine but not the TV.

Naturally I have checked that the resources retrieved do have templates that have the `projinfo` TV and that is all fine. I just dont know whats going on - this all seems correct to me. Can anyone help me out at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [`includeTVs`](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/getResources) flag.

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`5` &tpl=`projlink` &includeTVs=`1` ]]
```

Comment: depending on the content of the TV you may also have to use &processTVs. refer to the docs for specific case